# link an existing sharepoint site to the current site

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am currently having a sharepoint site collection which is in my sharepoint development environment (`http://Asa-PC:88/home/`)

I am also having a different sharepoint site collection (`http://Asa-PC:2222/sports/`), and my requirement is to add the sports sites home page as a page in home site collection, in other words, when I type `http://Asa-PC:88/home/sports/` in browser, it should redirect the user to sports site. How can I achieve this requirement?

Your inputs are highly appreciable..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Redirection options in SharePoint](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=48).

Also, I have used [SharePoint Smart 404](http://sharepointsmart404.codeplex.com/) before. However, that might be overkill for one page.